# Symfony Console Output with Escape Character

Tags: php, symfony, console

I'm generating a message with `sprintf()` that is then to be output with the [Symfony Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#coloring-the-output) in a colored fashion:

```
$mask = '<info>%s</info>';
$message = sprintf($mask, 'MyString');
$output->writeln($message);
```

This generally works (outputs the namespace in green). However if the string ends with a **backslash**, the closing *info*-tag is ignored:

```
$message = sprintf($mask, 'MyString\');
$output->writeln($message);
```

Output:

```
MyString</info>
        ^^^^^^^
```

Obviously the backslash seems to be a sort of escape character, but how to escape it? Or how to preserve the meaning of the closing `</info>` tag?

So far I tried with:

- `addcslashes('My\String\', '\\')` - does duplicate inside and single-fy at the end:

  ```
  My\\String\</info>
  ```
- `&#92;` as "HTML" entity, the HTML entity sequence is just output verbatim and the closing tag is gone:

  ```
  My&#92;String&#92;
  ```

Comment: try setting the decorate to false on the output as: `$output->setDecorated(false);`

Comment: if you can use the sf2.8 version I suggest you to use the SymfonyStyle component as described [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-console-style-guide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<` character can be escaped by a `\` as you already guessed. And the trailing backslashes can be escaped [from](https://github.com/symfony/console/commit/020e15e710bc52508bc3bb7ad1566d362ca86d85) Symfony v3.0.3, v2.8.3, v2.7.10 and v2.3.38 with `OutputFormatter`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter;

$mask = '<info>%s</info>';
$message = sprintf($mask, OutputFormatter::escape('MyString\\'));
$output->writeln($message);
```

Otherwise you can use:

```
$mask = "\033[32m%s\033[0m";
$message = sprintf($mask, 'MyString\\');
$output->writeln($message);
```

Comment: Yes, that's it :) Thanks a lot!